# D3 - ordinal scale labels with same names

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Just encountered a problem with D3.
I want a bar chart that displays a single bar for each data value. The problem is these labels have the same name.

Example:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
.domain(["Bob", "Bob", "Terry", "Joe", "Bob", "Terry", "Joe", "Shiva", "Terry", "Joe"])
.rangeBands([margin.left, width - margin.right, width], .35);
```

When viewed in the browser, all the data with the same name (e.g. `"Bob"`) is combined. In this case there are only four labels, whereas there should be 10.

How do I make it so that D3 treats each name as separate?
Also would be cool to have a solution where the names are stored in a data file (.json or .csv) where names are in `d.Name`

Comment: Scales map the same input to the same output. You'll need different input values for different bars if you're using a scale, e.g. by using the index instead of the name.

Comment: I don't understand index yet as I'm new to d3 -_- Is it something like this?
    `var obj = {};
    var nume = var1 + var2;
    obj[nume] = value;`

Comment: The index is the position of an element in an array.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use

```
const names = ["Bob", "Bob", "Terry", "Joe", "Bob", "Terry", "Joe", "Shiva", "Terry", "Joe"];

const x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(names.map((name, index) => index + name)) // it allows to create unique names
    .rangeBands([margin.left, width - margin.right, width], .35);

svg.selectAll('.x-axis .name-container').text((name) => name.substr(1)); // removing useless indexes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use linear and **tickFormat** for output

```
var raw = ["Bob", "Bob", "Terry", "Joe", "Bob", "Terry", "Joe", "Shiva", "Terry", "Joe"]

var linear = d3.scale.linear()
               .domain([0, raw.length])
               .range([0, w]);
```

**Add code below to your axis**

```
var axis = d3.svg.axis()
             .scale(linear)
             .orient("top")
             .ticks(raw.length)
             .tickFormat(function(d) {
               return raw.charAt(d);
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know ,**D3** using mathematical concept of domain and ranges of a function ( *`f(x)=y`* ) and strictly domain elements should be unique.

So make your domain unique, for example if you want Bob multiple times, you need to make Bob s as unique element by adding Bob-1, Bob-2, Bob-3 etc.

```
var x=d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["Bob1", "Bob2","Joe0", "Joe1", "Shiva", "Joe2"])
.rangeBands([0,500]);
```

Comment: This will, however, change the labels in the actual chart in the x axis. Is there anyway to change the labels to have these similar values?

Comment: Yes. Change the corresponding labels by selecting the  axis texts after rendering the axis. But This is not a good way, but it is also a solution for you.
Pseudo code: 

renderAxisAndPlots();
redrawTexts(){
// select duplicate names and give exact text.
d3.selectAll(".label").selectAll(".duplicate-label").attr("text",function(){return orginalText;}) 

}